# Oracle SQL : How to SELECT initial/final value of a FOR LOOP from a table?

Tags: sql, for-loop, select, plsql

I want to select final value of a for loop from a table, like this:
MyTable looks like this: ('Me',1) ('You',2)

`for i in 1..(SELECT MyID from MyTable where MYName = 'Me')`

But I get error message where SELECT appears.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the upper bound. Use something like this:

```
declare
  my_upper number;
begin
  select count(*) into my_upper
  from MyTable where MYNAME = 'Me';

  for i in 1..my_upper loop
    ... do something here ...
  end loop;
end;
```

see: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/controlstatements.htm#LNPLS004

Comment: But there is not several rows with MYNAME='Me'. I tried:
`declare
  my_upper number;
begin
  select MyID into my_upper
  from MyTable where MYNAME = 'Me';

  for i in 1..my_upper loop
    ... do something here ...
  end loop;
end;`

And it worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you know you will always return a single row, then use `select into`:

```
select myid into my_upper 
  from mytable 
 where namename = 'M';
```